# Did I just write a continuation?

Tags: haskell, continuations

I don't have formal knowledge of continuations, and am wondering if someone can help me verify and understand the code I wrote :).

#### Problem

The general problem I'm trying to solve is to convert expressions like

```
(2 * var) + (3 * var) == 4
```

into functions

```
\x y -> 2 * x + 3 * y == 4 -- (result)
```

which can be then passed into the `yices-painless` package.

#### Motivation

As a simpler example, note that `var` is translated into `\x -> x`. How can we multiply two `var`'s (denote them `\x -> x` and `\y -> y`) into one expression `\x -> \y -> x * y`?

I've heard continuations described as the "rest of computation", and thought that's what I need. Following that idea, a `var` should take a function

```
f :: α -> E -- rest of computation
```

whose argument will be the *value* of the variable `var` created, and return what we want (code listing marked `result`), a new function taking a variable `x` and returning `f x`. Hence, we define,

```
var' = \f -> (\x -> f x)
```

Then, for multiplication, say of `xf` and `yf` (which could be equal to `var`, for example), we want to take a "rest of computation" function `f :: α -> E` as above, and return a new function. We know what the function should do given the *values* of `xf` and `yf` (denoted `x` and `y` below), and define it as so,

```
mult xf yf = \f -> xf (\x -> yf (\y -> f (x Prelude.* y)))
```

#### Code

```
const' c = \f -> f c
var' = \f -> (\x -> f x) -- add a new argument, "x", to the function
add xf yf = \f -> xf (\x -> yf (\y -> f (x Prelude.+ y)))
mult xf yf = \f -> xf (\x -> yf (\y -> f (x Prelude.* y)))

v_α = var' -- "x"
v_β = var' -- "y"
v_γ = var' -- "z"
m = mult v_α v_β -- "x * y"
a = add m v_γ -- "x * y + z"
eval_six = (m id) 2 3
eval_seven = (a id) 2 3 1

two = const' 2 -- "2"
m2 = mult two v_γ -- "2 * z"
a2 = add m m2 -- "x * y + 2 * z"
eval_two = (m2 id) 1
eval_eight = (a2 id) 2 3 1

quad_ary = (var' `mult` var') `mult` (var' `mult` var')
eval_thirty = (quad_ary id) 1 2 3 5
```

well, it seems to work.

Comment: Start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation).

Comment: I've tried reading that a number of times... I dunno, but other people's explanations like the sandwich analogy really don't make sense to me. Maybe they'll make sense _after_ I understand continuations, but then they'll be less useful.

Comment: So true. And some people complain that monads are explained badly, sheesh.

Comment: Please don't use `α` or `β` in code!

Comment: @VladtheImpala, I think you're being a little English/US centric. OTOH I usually keep the usage to type variables, to keep those separate from code variables -- this is a little messier, I agree.

Comment: I really grasped continuations after learning Scheme, and having realized that `call/cc` "makes a hole" in the code. This may make sense to you one day. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is written in continuation passing style (CPS).

Somebody once explained continuations to me as "callbacks everywhere", which I didn't find particularly useful but maybe you will.

As seems true with so many things, probably the best you can do is to keep working on this to develop more fluency with the style.